# Stored procedure to list all weeks between two dates

Tags: mysql, date

I've searched but could not find a solution on how to list the weeks inbetween two dates.

I've found solutions that lists out all the days in the month between two dates:

```
select * from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date from
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2012-02-10' and '2012-02-15'
```

But nothing lists out the weeks as a 7 day week format, per below:

How would you do this?

Week Start: 2015-02-01 - Week End: 2015-02-07

Week Start: 2015-02-08 - Week End: 2015-02-14

Week Start: 2015-02-15 - Week End: 2015-02-21

Week Start: 2015-02-22 - Week End: 2015-02-28

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could select all days and filter on the first day of the week (`date_format(selected_date, '%w') = 0`):

```
select selected_date, date_add(selected_date, INTERVAL 6 DAY)
from 
(select adddate('1970-01-01',t4.i*10000 + t3.i*1000 + t2.i*100 + t1.i*10 + t0.i) selected_date 
 from
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t0,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t1,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t2,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t3,
(select 0 i union select 1 union select 2 union select 3 union select 4 union select 5 union select 6 union select 7 union select 8 union select 9) t4) v
where selected_date between '2015-02-01' and '2015-02-28'
  AND date_format(selected_date, '%w') = 0
```

SQLFIDDLE: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bc0e/52

You could use

`AND DAYOFWEEK(selected_date) = 1`

instead of

`date_format(selected_date, '%w') = 0`

I think it is a little bit more readable: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/7bc0e/54

Comment: Thanks man, I used this code with a yearweek() function to have a list of weeks I can query against. When using this against another table with a LEFT JOIN you get NULL values on the empty weeks. (instead of skipping that week).