# Split MonthStart MonthEnd dates into Weeks T-SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2012

I need to write a query that divides the below MonthStart & MonthEnd dates into 4 weeks. Below is the result set as of now. I would really appreciate if anyone can help me with writing this query. I need the query please.

```
MonthStartDate               MonthEndDate
2015-01-04 00:00:00.000      2015-01-31 00:00:00.000
```

I need result set to be like this.

```
WeekStartDate           WeekEndDate             MonthStartDate          MonthEndDate
2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 2015-01-10 00:00:00.000 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000
2015-01-11 00:00:00.000 2015-01-17 00:00:00.000 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000
2015-01-18 00:00:00.000 2015-01-24 00:00:00.000 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000
2015-01-25 00:00:00.000 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Stored procedure to list all weeks between two dates](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28571149/stored-procedure-to-list-all-weeks-between-two-dates)

Comment: APH, can you please write the query for me? I have read the link you provided but i did no understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Query

```
DECLARE @MonthStartDate DATETIME = '2015-01-04 00:00:00.000';              
DECLARE @MonthEndDate   DATETIME = '2015-01-31 00:00:00.000';


WITH X AS 
(
  SELECT TOP (DATEDIFF(DAY,@MonthStartDate,@MonthEndDate) + 1)
         DATEADD(DAY
                ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) -1
                ,@MonthStartDate) Dates
  FROM master..spt_values
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       DATEADD(DAY, -(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Dates)-1), Dates) AS [WeekStart]
      ,DATEADD(DAY, 7-(DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Dates)), Dates)  AS [WeekEnd] 
      ,@MonthStartDate                                    AS [MonthStartDate]
      ,@MonthEndDate                                      AS [MonthEndDate]
FROM X
```

### Result Set

```
╔═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╦═════════════════════════╗
║        WeekStart        ║         WeekEnd         ║     MonthStartDate      ║      MonthEndDate       ║
╠═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╬═════════════════════════╣
║ 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-10 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2015-01-11 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-17 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2015-01-18 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-24 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000 ║
║ 2015-01-25 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-04 00:00:00.000 ║ 2015-01-31 00:00:00.000 ║
╚═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╩═════════════════════════╝
```